Calling a .Net service from RPGLE
Hi Folks I am looking for some help in RPGLE or CBLLE for a requirement.

An RPGLE / CBLLE program which builds data in a Physical file
A .Net service which reads the data from the physical file and makes another service calls to perform a function
The .Net service performs the function and updates the Physical file on IBMi
The RPGLE / CBLLE in Step 1 then reads the Physical file and updates the transactional database

I have steps 2 and 3 ready on the .Net side, but need a way to integrate where I call this .Net service to let it know that the Physical file data is ready for its consumption and performs steps 2 and 3 and then the control returns back to step 4 for the same RPG to continue further.
Not sure if my explanation is clear here or not, but hoping to get some help here.
Regards,
Uday
Need hep calling a .Net function, Haven't tried anything yet

What you describe is what's known as a Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

when a computer program causes a procedure (subroutine) to execute in
a different address space (commonly on another computer on a shared
network), which is written as if it were a normal (local) procedure
call, without the programmer explicitly writing the details for the
remote interaction. That is, the programmer writes essentially the
same code whether the subroutine is local to the executing program, or
remote.

RPG doesn't support any RPC protocols.
The IBM i OS does include support for Open Network Computing (ONC) Remote Procedure Call (RPC); but that's probably way overkill.
Now-a-days, web services over HTTP are most often used for such distributed processing.
Another option is remote command execution.  The IBM i OS includes
Start PC Command (STRPCCMD)

which runs over the active 5250 session.

Run Remote Command (RUNRMTCMD)

which communicates to a REXECD (remote execution) daemon
transmits user name and password unencrypted
has fallen out of favor and been replaced by SSH


Thank you Charles. "web services over HTTP are most often used for such distributed processing." I think this is what I* am looking for may be. Are there any examples that could be shared that is helpful ?
